# Oracle APEX - displaying conditional prompt

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a form with a validation to check if the name entered already exists in the database and when submit button is clicked I want to proceed with an insert if the validation succeeds and if it fails, display a user prompt and if the user OK's it, then proceed with the update of existing record. I know how to do one of those at a time but not sure how to do this conditionally.

If I want to display a prompt I can use `redirect to URL` on a button click and set a prompt to whatever I want but how to only display a prompt when the validation fails?

Comment: What kind of feedback are you trying to get from the user? What are the options in terms of what happens after they provide the feedback you're looking for?

Comment: So if a name specified already exists (on insert), I need to prompt a user if they want to update existing record and if the user clicks OK then I can proceed with updating existing record. If record does not exist then just do the insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the followup comments, I would recommend the following:

1. Add a hidden item to the page, **P1_NAME_EXISTS**, for example. Ensure that its **Value Protected** setting is disabled.
2. Change the **Action** of the submit button to **Defined by Dynamic Action**.
3. Create a Dynamic Action on the click event of the button.
4. Make the first action an **Execute PL/SQL Code** action. Populate the **Items to Submit** property with the name of the item that has the name value you wish to validate. Then enter the PL/SQL code needed to see if the name is a duplicate. Set the value of P1_NAME_EXISTS to 'Y' or 'N' (or similar Boolean like values) within the PL/SQL code. Then put the name of the item (P1_NAME_EXISTS) in the **Items to Return** property of the action.
5. Add a second action. Set the **Action** to **Execute JavaScript Code**. Enter code like the following in the **Code** field:

   ```
   var nameExists = $v('P1_NAME_EXISTS') === 'Y';

   if (!nameExists) {
     apex.page.submit('SAVE');
   } else {
     apex.page.confirm('This name already exists. Would you like to update the existing entry?', 'SAVE');
   }
   ```

The JavaScript code will check the value of the hidden item after the PL/SQL process updates it. If the name doesn't already exist, then the page will just be submitted. If the name already exists, then the user will be prompted. Only if they click okay will the page be submitted.

You could change the value of the submit values if you needed to tell the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You create a declarative Validation. If your validation condition fails, you'll see the error you define, instead of normal processing.

In this case you could have validation based on existence of a row.

If all validations are fine, then page processing will commence.

All computations, validations, and processes can be conditional - either a nominated button, or a condition often based on valid of :REQUEST.

*Or*, you could have a constraint on the table that fails when the value already exists, and handle that with your APEX error function. Why do a pre-check when you can rely on DB constraints?

Comment: I do a pre-check because if a value already exists I need to communicate it to the user and get their input and proceed based on their input

Comment: By pre-check, I meant in the PL/SQL the moment before insert. If you're talking immediate UI response before submission of the form, consider Dan's response.